# Prove that every circle passing through a fixed point and having its centre on a fixed straight line must pass through another fixed point

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Prove that every circle passing through a fixed point and having its centre on a fixed straight line must pass through another fixed point

Please help me understand the question and provide me with a geometric proof

Comment: Well, draw a picture.  Can you work out where the other fixed point must be?

Comment: On the symmetrical opposite to the fixed point

Comment: Sure.  The reflection.  Once you have identified that point, it should be easy to prove the claim.

Comment: Any hint please

Comment: If $P$ is the point, $\overline P$ the reflection, let $X$ be the point on the line connecting $P,\overline P$ and let $Q$ be a random point on the fixed line.  Then show that the two triangles $\Delta PXQ$, $\Delta \overline PXQ$ are congruent,

Comment: Can you please provide a figure as I can't understand the triangles you are talking about

Comment: Please make an effort.

Comment: To be clear: $X$ is the point of intersection between the given fixed line and the line connecting $P,\overline P$.  It it the midpoint of the segment $P\overline P$.  The rest you should be able to do on your own.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help